# Citrix Receiver hangs at "Please wait for the Local Session Manager" and published application fails to launch

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, xenapp, multi-homed, citrix

When a user tries to connect to a Citrix XenApp 6.0 published application on a Windows 2008 R2 server, Citrix Receiver hangs at "Please wait for the Local Session Manager..." Eventually it times out and the application fails to load. When the user tries subsequent times, the application eventually loads.

This happens for users with and without administrator access and regardless of whether they are accessing the application directly or via Access Gateway. All recommended XenApp and Windows hotfixes have been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One domain controller in the environment has two NICs, one of which has an IP on a non-routed network. The server was registering this unroutable IP in DNS. The Citrix servers were attempting to authenticate users against the domain controller using this unreachable IP. Eventually the connection attempt would time out and the Citrix server would successfully authenticate against another domain controller.

The fix was to:

- Ensure `Register this connection’s addresses in DNS` was unchecked on the NIC's TCP/IP Advanced IP Settings under the DNS tab
- Issue the command `Netsh int ipv4 add address <Interface Name> <ip address> <subnet mask> skipassource=true` (https://support.microsoft.com/kb/975808)